# Problem, all rows in new column change to the result of last calculation performed

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to python and have researched to find an answer, I am most likely not asking the right question. I am streaming data from an exchange into a dataframe, will later stream the data into a databse, My problem is that when I do a calculation on a column to create a new column containing the result, all of the values of all rows in the new column change to the last result.

I am streaming in the open, high, low, close of a stock. In one column I am calculating the range for a candle during the timeframe, like on a one hour chart.

```
src = candles.close
ohlc = candles
ohlc = ohlc.rename(columns=str.lower)
candles['SMA_21'] = TA.SSMA(ohlc, period)
candles['EMA_21'] = TA.EMA(ohlc, period)
candles['WMA'] = TA.WMA(ohlc, 10)
   
  
candles['Range'] = src - candles['open']
    
candles['AvgRange'] = candles['Range'].tail(21).mean()
```

The range column works and has correct information which is not changed by each calculation. But the column for 'AvgRange' ends up with all values changed with each new mean value calculated.

The following also writes the last data entry to the whole column stream['EMA_Dir']

if stream['EMA'].iloc[-1] > stream['EMA'].iloc[-2]:

```
    stream['EMA_Dir'] = "Ascending"
```

I only want the last entry in the last, most recent, row of the dataframe.

Tried several things, but the last calculation changes all values in 'AvgRange' column.

Thanks in advance. Sorry if I didn't ask the question correctly, but that is probably why I haven't found the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
candles['AvgRange'] = candles[’range’].rolling(
window=3,
center=False
).mean()
```

this will give you a 3 row rolling average

Comment: Thank you very much for your input